# SELECT query with 2 condtions and the second condition is from the result of the first condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

so what I want to achieve is that there will be two select conditions which getting data from the same table but different conditions. where the condition of the second select is from the result of the first table but will still have joined results to display in the view.

```
SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE title_id = 1;
SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE song_id = tablea result;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The question is unclear see the link @AlivetoDie give to you.

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM table_name 
             WHERE ...) 
      AND ...
```

P.S.: Sharing your database schema would help us help you.

Comment: I see. so by this I can select from the same table and get data from the result of the first table?

Comment: Yeah, you can do just like that. just replace id w/ your primary key

Answer (score 0):

you use `sub-query` for this

```
SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE song_id = (SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE title_id = 1);
```

or use `join-query`

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tablea t1 left join tablea t2 on t2.song_id=t2.title_id
```